# App error on iOS simulator

Tags: ios, visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I was debugging my application earlier today from Visual Studio Cordova to iOS simulator running on a mac just fine.

After minimal changes, it would no longer run and seemed to crash instantly, giving the following errors in the system log:

```
Feb 22 14:59:28 Derricks-Air com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.FD118263-FDD1-4B7F-ADDB-0B5BA5811F88.launchd_sim[1946] (UIKitApplication:com.packagename.mail[0x8540][2832]): Program specified by service does not contain one of the requested architectures: ï
Feb 22 14:59:28 Derricks-Air SpringBoard[1962]: Unable to get pid for 'UIKitApplication:com.packagename.mail[0x8540]': No such process (err 3)
Feb 22 14:59:28 Derricks-Air SpringBoard[1962]: Bootstrapping failed for <FBApplicationProcess: 0x7d890cd0; com.packagename.mail; pid: -1>
Feb 22 14:59:28 Derricks-Air SpringBoard[1962]: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.packagename.mail[0x8540]' exited voluntarily.
```

I have since reverted any code changes and am still having this issue.

Any ideas?